# Can I use a Directv 4 way splitter to connect to an over the air TV antenna?

Tags: wiring, tv-antenna

I am replacing my Directv dish with an antenna for over-the-air TV.  I'm optimistic that I will not need to replace the splitter, but I'm uncertain.  The spects listed on the 4-way splitter are:

"DC Power Pass", 2 - 2150 MHz, Splitter SWM 4 Way, MSPLIT4R1-03

There is no external power plugged into it.  Here is a picture of the splitter:

[image]

The antenna that I will ideally be connecting directly to it lists the frequencies at 40~300MHz for VHF and 470~890 for UHF.  I assume those numbers are standard for those signals.

Will I have any issues connecting 4 TVs to the terminating ends of the split cables?

Comment: I suggest trying it. If it works, great. If not, disconnect the splitter and connect only one TV. If that works, then the splitter is causing an issue and you'll likely need to upgrade to a powered boosted splitter.

Answer (score 1):

SWM splitters aren't really splitters, they're active (powered) switches.  The power is applied to the cable on the input side.  [Here's a page on how they work](http://www.spectrumspot.com/solutions/swm-kit.html)

No harm to try, but I doubt it will work for you.  Passive splitters are fine if the runs from the splitter to the TV are short, and they're usually around $10 to $15.  If those runs are long, then you may benefit from a powered splitter.

Comment: How long would you consider a "long" run?  This SWM splitter runs about 30 feet, eand each line off of the splitting end runs somewhere between 10 and 30 feet itself.  It's outdoor, so powering it would be tricky.

Comment: That's not a very long run, but all the losses add up.  An efficient 4-way splitter would give you a 7-8 dB loss.  RG-6 over that distance is another 2dB+.  If you've got a powerful signal (not too far, very good antenna, good line-of-sight), then it'll be fine.  If you already have marginal signal, then a passive splitter may drop enough more to cause problems.

Comment: Another term for powered splitter is distribution amplifier. It amplifies the signal just enough to reduce the loss you normally experience with a passive splitter. Often, 4-way passive splitters tend to cause too much loss on an antenna system.